# jQuery.when() need to be cleared up

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

I have a simple .html page like this :

```
</html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
...
<script type="text/javascript">

var obj;             

function document_load() {
      obj = new mySpace.myClass(); 
      console.log("end document load");          
   }


</script>
</head>
<body onload="document_load()">
...
...
</body>
</html>
```

myClass is a TypeScript class with this constructor :

```
 public constructor() {

    console.log("begin constructor");

    (<any>$).when(

      jQuery.getJSON('path/myJson1.json', function (data) {
       this.obj1 = data;
       console.log("here1");
        }),

       jQuery.getJSON('path/myJson2.json', function (data) {
       this.obj2 = data;
       console.log("here2");
        })

       ).then(function () {

          if (this.obj1 && this.obj2) {

           console.log("here3");
           this.obj3 = new myClass3();
           this.obj4 = new myClass4(); 
           console.log("everything went ok");

        }
     });
   }
```

Actually the console prints this :

```
begin constructor
end document load
here1
here2
```

The reason of this behaviour is (of course) cause of asynchronous jQuery calls (or at least I guess). How can I obtain the following behaviour?

```
begin constructor
here1
here2
here3
everything went ok
end document load
```

I clarify that the jsons are taken correctly (I tried to print them and they are correct).

Comment: I'd suggest to have a look at [Is it bad practice to have a constructor function return a Promise?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24398699/1048572)

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're not returning a promise to jQuery.when, so the callback gets called and `this.obj1 && this.obj2` are both null.

A better way to do this would be:

```
(<any>$).when(

    jQuery.getJSON('path/myJson1.json'),

    jQuery.getJSON('path/myJson2.json')

)
.then(function (obj1, obj2) {
    // Code
});
```

Comment: He *does* pass promises to `$.when`, but that doesn't fix the `this` context of his callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

Replace all functions with arrow functions (=>). This will ensure that "this" points to the correct thing in all function bodies.

More : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tvocUcbCupA

Comment: I think the problem is not only the "this" statement. In fact, if I try to remove the "if" clause, the console print [ begin constructor,end document load,here1,here2,here3,everything went ok ]